# Weaknesses in vanity PGP keys

Tags: rsa, pgp

The program [Scallion](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion) can generate vanity PGP keys and .onion addresses using the following method:

> 1. Generate RSA key using OpenSSL on the CPU
> 2. Send the key to the GPU
> 3. Increase the key's public exponent
> 4. Hash the key
> 5. If the hashed key is not a partial collision go to step 3
> 6. If the key does not pass the sanity checks recommended by PKCS #1 v2.1 (checked on the CPU) go to step 3
> 7. Brand new key with partial collision!

As RSA is susceptible to various attacks when its parameters are not properly selected, e.g. [small difference of prime factors](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/profs/informatique/Francois.Morain/Master1/Crypto/projects/Weger02.pdf), does this method of iteratively increasing the public exponent yield any weaknesses in the generated keys?

Of course, it is possible to generate a key with a fingerprint you desire using `gpg` itself but it is much slower.

Comment: Interesting question. I can't think of any weaknesses off the top of my head. How long do we wait without an answer before we assume that there is no weakness? In other words, I doubt anyone can prove that there is no weakness.

Comment: @mikeazo Actually, any choice of public exponent is equally good as long as we don't induce a short private exponent, but this should be caught by step 6. So at the end we get a "normal" RSA key-pair that passes all known checks for bad properties, the fact that we tried many others before that should be irrelevant.

Comment: @SEJPM, good point. I forgot that the algorithm was to change the exponent. For some reason I was thinking tweaking the primes was the approach. Sounds like a good answer to me if you want to write it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is fine (if it does actually check for short private exponents).

Any choice of public exponent is functionally and security-wise equivalent as long as it doesn't induce a short private exponent and as long as it is co-prime to [$\lambda(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). The latter being caught by the fact that key generation won't be able to finish and the former being caught by the PKCS#1 v2.1 induced check (which I couldn't actually find, so beware!), which should check for short private exponents.